# UIWebView domain verification

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, safari

All HI!
It is necessary that the address changes in the UIWebView to check the domain, and if this changed - open the page in Safari.
Is there a way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

There is

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

method in UIWebViewDelegate protocol.
There you can check if domain is changed

```
NSURL* newURL = [request URL];
```

and if it does, return open Safari with this URL and return NO.